# MakeIndex rejects all indices

Tags: errors, makeindex

I am using MikTeX and my version of makeindex is `2.15`.

A simple document like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be used 
which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index{Index}.

Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} will 
also show up. 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

will result in this output after running `pdflatex` and `makeindex` on it:

```
Scanning input file test.tex...done (0 entries accepted, 12 rejected).
Nothing written in test.ind.
Transcript written in test.ilg.
```

However, in my .idx, I clearly have all the proper indices that makeindex was supposed to create:

```
\indexentry{keywords}{1}
\indexentry{Index}{1}
\indexentry{generate}{1}
\indexentry{others}{1}
```

Nevertheless, nothing is written in .ind as the log states.
Is this a bug?

Comment: You have only 4 `\index` commands but 12 index entries are rejected? You've run `makeindex` for the wrong file.

Comment: You have to run `makeindex` on `test.idx`, not on `test.tex`. On the other hand, you don't need to run `makeindex`, because `imakeidx` does it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Silly me. I was skipping back and forth between `pdflatex test.tex` and `makeindex test.idx` and somewhere there the mistake must have sneaked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run LaTeX over your file, say `filename.tex`, an auxiliary file `filename.idx` is produced.

This is the file `makeindex` should process; calling

```
makeindex filename
```

will choose the right extension `.idx`, so it's not necessary to include it.

On the other hand, the normal operation of `imakeidx` is to run `makeindex` automatically, so this further run is not needed, unless the `noautomatic` option is passed to the package.